# Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '('2022/11/29/oddballers-29112022',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['page/(?P<key>[^/]+)\\\\Z']

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I'm getting error NoReverseMatch at /, here I'm trying to catch the key like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQMLU.png)

and I can't get the key, when I take it and an error like the one above comes out

The code details are like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xZXT.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VzwI.png)

detail error like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WUOO.png)

thank you.

what I want is to capture the key and then I make it as a parameter for the details of the article, when I catch the key but what comes out is an error.. sorry if my English is difficult to understand, I'm not good at English

Comment: Please add code to your question as formatted text and not images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `path` [path converter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/urls/#path-converters) instead of `str` if you wish to pass/capture values containing forward slash in your urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('page/<path:key>', detailt_page, name='detail'),
]
```